# How to write double string NFC to a single Tag

Tags: java, nfc

I am making a attendance application that uses NFC technology. An NFC tag act as the student ID.
however I need to input atleast two (2) data from student to the tag. I came across on a video on yt and copy the whole code and add two lines because I need two data but it seems it doesnt work lol! i hope you help me with this one

this is my code

`````
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


public class writeHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String Error_Detected = "No NFC Tag Detected!";
    public static final String Write_Success = "Text Written Successfully!";
    public static final String Write_Error = "Error during Writing, Try again!";
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter[] writingTagFilters;
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;
    TextView editTextTextPersonName7;
    TextView editTextTextPersonName3;
    // read
    Button button2;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_home);
        editTextTextPersonName7 = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName7);
        editTextTextPersonName3 = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName3);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        context = this;
        button2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            try {
                if(myTag == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Error_Detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    write(editTextTextPersonName7.getText().toString(), myTag);
                    write(editTextTextPersonName3.getText().toString(), myTag);
                    Toast.makeText(context, Write_Success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if(nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support NFC!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        readFromIntent(getIntent());
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        writingTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };


    }
    private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i< rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }
    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
        String text2 = "";
        byte [] payload = msgs [0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload [0]&128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 51;

        try {
            text= new String(payload, languageCodeLength +1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }
        //output
        editTextTextPersonName7.setText(text);
        editTextTextPersonName3.setText(text2);
    }
    private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
        NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        ndef.connect();
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
        ndef.close();
    }
    private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) {
        String lang         = "en";
        byte[] textBytes    = text.getBytes();
        byte[] langBytes    = lang.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        int langLength      = langBytes.length;
        int textLength      = textBytes.length;
        byte[] payload      = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

        payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1, langLength);
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1+langLength, textLength);

        return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        readFromIntent(intent);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        WriteModeOff();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        WriteModeOn();
    }
    //write & read switches
    private void WriteModeOn() {
        writeMode = true;
        String[][] techList = new String[][] { { android.nfc.tech.Ndef.class.getName() }, { android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable.class.getName() } };
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writingTagFilters,techList);
    }

    private void WriteModeOff() {
        writeMode = false;
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

}````

I don't know much of these as I am new to programming. Can someone teach me how to make this work? Also I put this in a way that the output can be viewed on the input section if that make sense. I just copy this code from youtube so I didnt expect this to work at all. thanks!

I tried to read as much I can understand but I really don't know what to do so I wrote another question even though this was already ask before. 

I just want to record two string data into NFC tag 

also if you want to rewrite the code with the same id that would be great! thanks!
`````

Comment: You can't write two "full" NdefMessages to a tag, the standard way is to write ONE NdefMessage that contains TWO NdefRecords. Depending on your workflow - why don't you write both strings in one message ?

Comment: i want to use the string seperately as variable